# Не могу настроить VPN в lubuntu

Tags: linux, vpn, lubuntu

Пытаюсь подключиться к удалённому впн хосту, имея адрес и пароль. В lubuntu создание впн подключения отличается от остальных линуксов. Есть поля
Address
Netmask
Gateway
В сетевую маску вбил 255.255.255.255
В адрес и в маршрут вбил ip хоста.
Выдаёт
invalid setting VPN: unspecified error.
Есть ещё вкладка routes, там добавилась графа metric.

Comment: Я думаю, вам стоить привести более подробную информацию.

Comment: Выглядит как поток сознания. Уточните ваш вопрос, и вам помогут. Иначе канет в лету